# Cmakeでヘッダーオンリーのライブラリをincludeしたい

Tags: c++, cmake

[ToruNiina/toml11](https://github.com/ToruNiina/toml11) というtomlのparserを使いたいのですが、どうやらこのライブラリは `.hpp` だけで構成されるヘッダーオンリーというものらしいのです。これをcmakeでインクルードする方法を教えてください！

そもそも上記のライブラリの場合、具体的にどのフォルダやファイルを自分の環境に置けばいいのでしょうか？
`toml.hpp`ファイルと`toml`フォルダの二点でしょうか？
また、それらはどのように配置したらよいのでしょうか

- 何をダウンロードして
- どのように配置すればいいのか
- Cmakeはどうしたらいいのか(多分include_directoryで指定すればいいとは思うんですが)

を教えてください。 m(_ _)m

Comment: 先にこちらで回答が付いているようですが、それでは駄目だったのでしょうか。[Cmakeでヘッダーオンリーのライブラリをincludeしたいです！](https://teratail.com/questions/279992) あるいはもしかしたら英語の古い記事が今も該当するかも。[In CLion, header only library: file "does not belong to any project target, code insight features might not work properly"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46245738/9014308) 日本語化記事 [CLionでは、ヘッダーのみのライブラリ：ファイルは「どのプロジェクトターゲットにも属していません。コード洞察機能が正しく動作しない可能性があります」](https://www.it-swarm-ja.tech/ja/c++/834493314/)

Comment: この投稿をした後に返信が来たため気が付きませんでした。
確認したところ解決しました。
わざわざありがとうございました！

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[vcpkg](https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg)というパッケージマネージャを使うのはどうでしょうか？ toml11にもDetoursにも対応しているのでパッケージとして追加するだけです。

Comment: ありがとうございます。パッケージマネージャーは欲しいと思っていたので、今から試しに入れてみます